# Assesment tool for DB2, MariaDB, MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, db2, mariadb, inventory

Do we have any substitute tool like 'Microsoft Assessment planning toolkit(MAPS)' which is used for assessing SQL server/Oracle inventory and database details, for assessing DB2\MongoDB\MariabDB database.
Do we have any tool that can be used to assess database in depth details for DB2\MongoDB\MariabDB databases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems 'IBM Data Studio' or 'Toad for Db2' or 'DB Visualiser' are the possible alternatives for Db2 databases.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Azure Migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/migrate-services-overview#:%7E:text=Azure%20Migrate%20provides%20a%20centralized,tools%20for%20assessment%20and%20migration.) but it works well if your machines are on VMWare or Hyper-V.
Less well if you are on Azure-VM.

I haven't tried it on AWS, GCP